# login callback don't run with facebook account kit after success login?

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, sms, account-kit

hello i want to implement facebook account kit to login with sms on my localhost i follow the code as in the docs

```
<script>
  // initialize Account Kit with CSRF protection
  AccountKit_OnInteractive = function(){
    AccountKit.init(
      {
        appId:"{{FACEBOOK_APP_ID}}", 
        state:"{{csrf}}", 
        version:"{{ACCOUNT_KIT_API_VERSION}}",
        fbAppEventsEnabled:true,
        redirect:"{{REDIRECT_URL}}"
      }
    );
  };

  // login callback
  function loginCallback(response) {
    if (response.status === "PARTIALLY_AUTHENTICATED") {
      var code = response.code;
      var csrf = response.state;
      // Send code to server to exchange for access token
    }
    else if (response.status === "NOT_AUTHENTICATED") {
      // handle authentication failure
    }
    else if (response.status === "BAD_PARAMS") {
      // handle bad parameters
    }
  }

  // phone form submission handler
  function smsLogin() {
    var countryCode = document.getElementById("country_code").value;
    var phoneNumber = document.getElementById("phone_number").value;
    AccountKit.login(
      'PHONE', 
      {countryCode: countryCode, phoneNumber: phoneNumber}, // will use default values if not specified
      loginCallback
    );
  }


  // email form submission handler
  function emailLogin() {
    var emailAddress = document.getElementById("email").value;
    AccountKit.login(
      'EMAIL',
      {emailAddress: emailAddress},
      loginCallback
    );
  }
</script>
```

everything work as charm i enter phone and i receive sms then i verify the code and now is the problem after the code verify the login call back should be excuted so i can connect with the server but this method never execute, why?

notes: my app in development
       i enabled debug true but there is no problem shown on console

i try many thing but nothing worked the login callback never run

so how i can make the login call back executed so i can connect with server?

Comment: Are you sure it never got called at all - or does maybe simply none of your three conditions actually match?

Comment: Where is the code which will process on your server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some ajax mechanism after this line:

var csrf = response.state;